# Simple Nim Game

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

I recently learnt the basic strategy of Nim game where there are piles of elements. Then one have to chose a pile and remove any number of elements from that pile. I found some problem that is said to be Nim but I couldn't convert it to the standard Nim problem representing the pile.

Problem says there is a square checker board like chess difference is - only pawn is present here. So in each column there are two pawns - one white and one black. No pawn can overtake it's opposite but it can move back and forth unlike chess where pawns can move only forward. They can't change column like chess by eating up opponent pawn. Game ends when any side have no option to give a move. Given initial configuration of pawns the program need to output the winner - white / black.

Any idea on how to convert it to standard one?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. It's a game theory question. I would suggest consulting *Winning Ways* by Berlekamp, Conway, and Guy. It studies all sorts of variations of Nim, among many other things.

Comment: @RaymondChen You got me interested in this book. Is there any free pdf version available of this book?

Comment: The book is still in print. You can ask the publisher. Your game is eight-lane Frogs and Toads.

Comment: I think that if each pawn is adjacent to its opponent in the same column then the player whose turn it is will eventually lose to good play. I think that getting to this state might be a game of nim where the numbers are the number of squares between pawns in each column - but this only a comment because I have not proved this.

Comment: @mcdowella, thanks for your reply. I got the code accepted using the same idea as you - no of blocks between two pawns in each column.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that each move changes the parity of sum of distances between corresponding pawns. Calculate the parity, the current player wins IFF the sum is odd (because if it's odd current player can always move a pawn forward)